How to calculate sales customers in last 2 months from current month
How to calculate sales customers in last 2 months from current month using DAX
I used the below DAX:
calculate(distinctcount(customerid), datesinperiod(date[date], eomonth(today(),0), -2, month)
But the result is blank. I don't know why?

I think it should work


maybe you need to minimize your data to see if this works. Then apply it to your whole data.

Thanks for the response. But the dax is same with I shared. The output is blank. Is there a better approach to it?

could you pls provide some sample data or pbix file?

Thanks everyone for the response. I have finally solved the problem. It's just a tweak in the dax formula. Here is the correct dax: calculate(distinctcount(customerid), datesinperiod(date[date], max(date[date]), -2, month)
